# keep text from moving

Tags: javascript, html

I have a span tag inside of a paragraph that updates every second, and whenever it does, it keeps on shifting the text either to the right or left:

```js
setInterval(() => {document.querySelector("#fruits").innerHTML = Date.now() % 20}, 1)
```

```html
<p>Here is some text "<span id="fruits"></span>" Here is some more text</p>
```

How can I prevent the words from moving?

Comment: Use a mono spaced font? Make the element a fixed width?

Comment: You could zero pad the integers then it would always be the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style `style="display: inline-block;width: 15px;"` on span `#fruits`

```js
setInterval(() => {document.querySelector("#fruits").innerHTML = Date.now() % 20}, 1);
```

```html
<p>Here is some text "<span id="fruits" style="display: inline-block;width: 15px;"></span>" Here is some more text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a padding of `"0"` would fix the issue. That way it's anticipating two digits at all times.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelector("#fruits").innerHTML = (Date.now() % 20)
    .toLocaleString('en-US', {
      minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
      useGrouping: false
    })
}, 1)
```

```html
<p>Here is some text "<span id="fruits"></span>" Here is some more text</p>
```

Comment: I like your approach but it forces me to add multiple digits to the result